# Manhattan Distance Recommending system Python

Tags: python, distance

So I've been trying this for a while now but just can't get it work. If you look in the picture you see 2 people in the x and y axes and both are the ratings they gave to movies. And the question is how can I calculate the manhattan distance between these to people.

[image]

so this is what I already have...
**edit**
i forgot to say that prefs is a dict with personname as key and and a second dict as the value. second dict contains movies as key and rating as value.. and the person1 and 2 are just strings with name which can be found in prefs

```
def sum_manhattan(prefs,person1,person2):
    """Calculates the Manhattan distance between two critics"""
    total = 0
    ##assume person1 is the x axes and person 2 is the y axes
    x = prefs[person1]
    y = prefs[person2]

    for movie in x:
        if movie in y:
            total = abs(x[movie]-y[movie])
    return total
```

any help is welcome :)

Comment: What exactly is not working? I see that in the loop you do total = abs(...). Is that what you do in your program or is it something you mistyped in the question?

Comment: Are we to assume that prefs, person1, and person2 are structured the same as they are in Programming Collective Intelligence (where the image was lifted from)? http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1066-how-to-find-similar-users-with-python/

Comment: i'm sorry.. yes that is exactly what it is but it is what my professor gave me
and i forgot to say that prefs is a dict with personname as key and and a second dict as the value. second dict contains movies as key and rating as value.. and the person1 and 2 are just strings with name which can be found in prefs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the link posted by Alkini, I'd say that you should replace

```
total = abs(x[movie]-y[movie])
```

with

```
total += abs(x[movie]-y[movie])
```

to make things work.

What the code you posted does is return the absolute value of the difference between the ratings of the last movie, while I think you need to add the ratings differences for all movies.

Comment: arg yea that is it! it's very stupid of me not to have seen that :P
but anyways thank you!